# Visual Studio debugger-like object visualizer

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls, visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible to use Visual Studio's visualizers of values that exist in debugger?
I mean visualizer that allows to expand nested child objects, displays collections and so forth.

Or is there any kind of WPF control that behaves similar to VS's one?

I would like to use it in Visual Studio extension.

Comment: I have seen PropertyGrid from Extended WPF Toolkit. This control is an analog of VS's Properties window. And I want something that looks and behaves like object visualizer that works in debugger or in Watches window, that allows to expand nested properties etc. I understand that they two are similar, but PropertyGrid is too heavy for me, I need something more light and compact visually. And I think I do not need properties editing.

Comment: This seems to be close to what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668802/looking-for-an-object-graph-tree-view-control-for-wpf

Comment: And to more directly answer your question, no, the ones we use in VS aren't reusable outside of VS.

Comment: I would like to use this control inside of Visual Studio in extension. Is it possible to do?