# Creating Dynamic Views for classes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Ok i've asked a previous question on this but i think I need to take a step back and ask a different question.

What i'm trying to do here is create an editor for a field decoded from a game (a modding tool), these files are decoded by a 3rd party library and added to a class which is passed back.

Now there are over 1000 varients of this class which all share the baseclass `NMSTemplate`, each has it's own unique properties which can be anything from a basic object (string, int) to a collection of other varients of `NMSTemplate`.

I've tried numerous ways to do this, and my latest is something like follows

```
IOrderedEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = template.GetType().GetFields().OrderBy(field => field.MetadataToken);

        foreach(FieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            MBINField field = new MBINField()
            {
                Name = f.Name,
                Value = f.GetValue(null),
                NMSType = f.FieldType.Name
            };
            _fields.Add(field);
        }
```

I then bind a listview to this field collection, and use a datatemplate to change how it's displayed

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MbinListTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MbinTemplateSelector}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MbinStringTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now appart from issues getting the value from FieldInfo, i realised that i've hit a pitfall when I run into a Property that is a collection of `NMSTemplate` i'm not sure how i can then also handle the dynamic showing of the properties of classes in that collection.

Comment: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid

Comment: Hey ASh, thanks for that link it looks very promising, i'll have to take a proper look, Thanks!

Comment: Well, propertygrid won't work in my situation unfortunatly. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I've spun up my own reflection object viewer in the past, but here is a similar approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668802/looking-for-an-object-graph-tree-view-control-for-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your question correctly but you could try to check for the field type and handle each type separately. Here's and example to handle the field of type `List<NMSTemplate>`

```
var fields = template.GetType().GetFields().OrderBy(field => field.MetadataToken);
foreach(var f in fields)
{
    var isGeneric = f.FieldType.IsGenericType;
    var isList = f.FieldType == typeof(List<NMSTemplate>);

    if(isGeneric && isList)
    {                        
        var value = f.GetValue(template);
        var list = (List<NMSTemplate>)value;

        foreach(var listEntry in list)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the foreach loop you can than create all the `MBINField` objects and add them to the `_fields` list.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I've been playing around with this and i'm run into an issue. islist always returns false and i cannot cast to List<NMSTemplate> even tho the objects in the list all inherit from NMSTemplate

Comment: @Ben how is the declaration of your collection? `List<NMSTemplate>` was just an example. You've to replace it with the correct type..

Comment: Ah, I assumed because they all inherit from NMSTemplate i could get away with using that. I'll need to work out a way of getting the correct type.

Comment: Ok, so someone advised me to use dynamic to solve this issue, and that worked :D thanks